# What kind of messages does Windows send to applications?

Tags: windows, process, architecture

What kind of messages does Windows send to applications? For example, when I click this Firefox window, what does happen? Does Windows find the process ID of the application and send it some message or what?

I am looking for this kind of detail for a research. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate that!

Comment: I believe Windows uses handles - http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson05.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Win32 API for user->process, process<->process and OS<->process interaction is message based.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows for a very basic intro and some useful links to relevant documentation at Microsoft including http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0795/dilascia/dilascia.aspx which seems a fairly complete walk around the subject (though may assume some existing Windows programming knowledge).